# Using Two Values for a Chunk Option in knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm wanting the results from my chunks in R Markdown using knitr to output at the end of the chunk as done by specifying `results="hold"` but also need the output to be `results="asis"`.

Is this possible? I found `fig.show` but I also have tables I'm outputting.

Comment: You may try wrapping your output in `knitr::asis_output`